# How to create a scikit pipeline for tf-idf vectorizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, tf-idf

I was going through this official sklearn [tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html) how to create pipeline for text data analysis and use it later for grid search. But, I encountered a problem and the given methods does not work for this case.

I want this code to work:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from mlxtend.feature_selection import ColumnSelector
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer


df_Xtrain = pd.DataFrame({'tweet': ['This is a tweet']*10,
                          'label': 0})
y_train = df_Xtrain['label'].to_numpy().ravel()

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('col_selector', ColumnSelector(cols=('tweet'))),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('bernoulli', BernoulliNB()),
])


pipe.fit(df_Xtrain,y_train)
```

This code works:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from mlxtend.feature_selection import ColumnSelector
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# data
df_Xtrain = pd.DataFrame({'tweet': ['This is a tweet']*10,
                          'label': 0})
y_train = df_Xtrain['label'].to_numpy().ravel()

# modelling
mc = 'tweet'
vec_tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()

vec_tfidf.fit(df_Xtrain[mc])

X_train = vec_tfidf.transform(df_Xtrain[mc]).toarray()


model = BernoulliNB()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
model.predict(X_train)
model.score(X_train,y_train)
```

#### Question

How to make a pipeline for text analysis like above?

#### Update

Versions

```
[('numpy', '1.17.5'),
 ('pandas', '1.0.5'),
 ('sklearn', '0.23.1'),
 ('mlxtend', '0.17.0')]

Python 3.7.7
```

## Error Log

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3012ce7245d9> in <module>
     19 
     20 
---> 21 pipe.fit(df_Xtrain,y_train)

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/spk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    328         """
    329         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 330         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    331         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    332                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/spk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    294                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
    295                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 296                 **fit_params_steps[name])
    297             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    298             # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/spk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    350 
    351     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 352         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/spk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    738     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    739         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 740             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    741         else:
    742             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/spk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    691         else:
    692             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 693             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    694 
    695 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/spk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in fit(self, X, y)
   1429             A matrix of term/token counts.
   1430         """
-> 1431         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=('csr', 'csc'))
   1432         if not sp.issparse(X):
   1433             X = sp.csr_matrix(X)

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/spk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/spk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    597                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    598                 else:
--> 599                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    600             except ComplexWarning:
    601                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/spk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'This is a tweet'
```

Comment: *"I encountered a problem and the given methods does not work for this case"* is totally vague description, we need details, questions on SO are required to be [MCVE]. Please the specific error, traceback and show which line of code caused it. Then, show us what steps you took to debug it yourself, and what specifically you're stuck on,

Comment: Also, it goes without saying please post your version of Python (3.7?/8?), numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, mlxtend packages etc., and again if you use Anaconda (which version?) as package manager, and the OS and version if that's implicated in your error.

Comment: Do check my answer, should solve your issue.

Comment: Still missing the crucial information: please post the specific error, traceback and show which line of code caused it.

Comment: Ok thanks for finally posting. You should still clarify what the issue is in the question text, not just *"this code doesn't work"* (It's not good practice to make questions entirely reliant on the specific details of the code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 main issues with your code -

1. You are using a `tfidftransformer`, without using a `countvectorizer` before it. Instead, just use a `tfidfvectorizer` which does both in one go.
2. Your `columnselector` is returning a 2D array `(n,1)` while a `tfidfvectorizer` expects a 1D array `(n,)`. This can be done by setting the param `drop_axis = True`.

Making the above changes, this should work -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from mlxtend.feature_selection import ColumnSelector
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB



df_Xtrain = pd.DataFrame({'tweet': ['This is a tweet']*10,
                          'label': 0})
y_train = df_Xtrain['label'].to_numpy().ravel()

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('col_selector', ColumnSelector(cols=('tweet'),drop_axis=True)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('bernoulli', BernoulliNB()),
])


pipe.fit(df_Xtrain,y_train)
```

```
Pipeline(steps=[('col_selector', ColumnSelector(cols='tweet', drop_axis=True)),
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()), ('bernoulli', BernoulliNB())])
```

---

EDIT: Response to question asked - "Is this possible without the mlxtend package? Why I need the ColumnSelector here? Is there a solution with sklearn only?"

Yes, as I mention below, you will have to build your own column selector class (and this is how you build your own transformers to add to your pipeline as well).

```
class SelectColumnsTransformer():
    def __init__(self, columns=None):
        self.columns = columns

    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        cpy_df = X[self.columns].copy()
        return cpy_df

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self


# Add it to a pipeline 
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('selector', SelectColumnsTransformer([<input col name here>]))
])
```

Refer to [this link](https://queirozf.com/entries/scikit-learn-pipelines-custom-pipelines-and-pandas-integration#custom-transformer-example-select-dataframe-columns) for more information on how you can play around with this.

Comment: Is this possible without the mlxtend package? Why I need the ColumnSelector here? Is there a solution with sklearn only?